# Bash to loop over two columns but just print the first columns and on second run the desired command

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

i have a bash script where i want echo two distinct fields and combine the command output into it to make it a single line.

I am reading from a `csv` file two columns that's `$2` which is a project name and another `$NF` which is a volume name. where i am running a command against each volume in a for loop to get the data but i want `project and $2` also be printed along with each volume name in a echo command So, i could know a particular project have particular data.

below is sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
s_list=$(cat ldap-project-nismap.csv | tr "," "\t"| awk '{print $2, $NF}'| tr -d '"'|sed 1d|head -5)
echo $s_list
for name in $(echo "$s_list");
  do
    echo -n "$2: $NF"
    # do Some action on "$NF"
    locate $NF
done
```

**CSV DATA SAMPLE:**

```
"DC_oregon-DC01",dnpc,"dbc2002:/proj/dbc2002_dnpc_eaeagle_pd2/q",1000,"761.87",76,economy,"eaeagle_pd2","dbc2002_dnpc_eaeagle_pd2"
"DC_oregon-DC01",dnpc,"dbc2002:/proj/dbc2002_dnpc_eaeagle2_7/q",4096,"3536.99",86,scratch,"eaeagle2_7","dbc2002_dnpc_eaeagle2_7"
"DC_oregon-DC01",dnpc,"dbc2002:/proj/dbc2002_dnpc_eaeagle2_6/q",4096,"2976.74",73,scratch,"eaeagle
```

Below is the `s_list` list which contains `Project Name` and `Volume Name`.

```
d62320 fxn3008_d62320 d62200 fxn3008_d62200 d62150 fxn3008_d62150 d62110 fxn3008_d62110 d62100 fxn3008_d62100
```

**Below is what it looks like:**

```
Project_name   Volume_name
d62320         fxn3008_d62320 
d62200         fxn3008_d62200 
d62150         fxn3008_d62150 
d62110         fxn3008_d62110 
d62100         fxn3008_d62100
```

**What is desired:**

```
d62320:fxn3008_d62320:/q/volset/fxn3008_d62320
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get rid of `cat` `tr` `sed` `head` with a single `awk`.

Also, the `locate` command uses a pattern; it might not be a problem with your volumes names but at the very least you need to prepend `*/` to them.

```bash
awk -F, '2 <= NR && NR <= 6 {gsub(/"/,""); print $2,$NF}' file.csv |

while read -r project volume
do
    path=$(locate -n 1 "*/$volume")
    printf '%s:%s:%s\n' "$project" "$volume" "$path"
done
```

**remark:** parsing a CSV this way only works when there isn't any  comma nor double-quote nor newline embedded in the fields data.

Comment: @ Fravadona, thanks you very much, this looks promising solution. +1 already , let me try this to my code and then i can accept this as a answer, `locate` command is just an example.